# Fix for ugly fonts in programs like KeePassXC or Nextcloud on Antergos with Gnome3

Tags: gnome, fonts, antergos, nextcloud, keepassx

Using Antergos, I see ugly font rendering issues in some applications I installed like KeePassXC or also the Nextcloud client (both from AUR) as you can see on the following screenshot:

[image]

I like a smooth font rendering like in the default apps. Thought that they may use Windows fonts, so I copied the entire `Fonts` folder from a Windows 10 ISO to `/usr/share/fonts`. This has an effect, but as you can see on the following screenshots, it looks a bit wired/big. With some touch of *Courier new* or a similar font.

[image]

On the [official screenshots from the KeePassXC homepage](https://keepassxc.org/images/screenshots/linux/screen_001.png) it looks way smoother:
[image]

I know that this is KDE and I'm using Gnome. How can I realize a similar look to the KDE screenshots? I don't know which fonts are used and which I need to install. And I also can't understand why copying the fonts from a Windows system doesn't fix this issue. Since the look changed after doing this, it seems that my idea of missing Windows fonts is basically right.

#### Update 1: Font resolution

In [gui/Font.cpp](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/blob/d8f408ee831adce6f6d2b81da1519cbb6efae577/src/gui/Font.cpp) we can see that KeePassXC uses consolas font, but only on Windows. So I took a look in the Gnome optimization settings and found an entry:

[image]

The last one seems similar to my second screenshot. But it has no effect on KeePassXC. Only the font in my terminal changes. I don't understand why the second font for the interface is not used in KeePassXC. When I change this font, all entrys of e.g. Firefox were displayed as I set it.

#### Update 2

I installed [adwaita-qt5](https://web.archive.org/web/20161227150814/https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/adwaita-qt5/) and set the style on startup like this:

```
keepassxc -style adwaita
```

Doesn't have any affect. Altough it seems that he uses the style, since before installing the `adwaita-qt5` package, I got an error

> QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it

This error was gone after installing the package.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with KeePassX. My understanding is that it's due to the QT theme, which is configured in `.config/Trolltech.conf` for QT4. If you set it to `GTK+`, the application will be themed as a GTK application:

```
[Qt]
style=GTK+
```

This is for QT4 thought, if KeePassXC is using QT5 the theme configuration is done differently it seems. There's some info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Qt5)

Comment: I can confirm that this doesnt help in current versions with qt5. In these documentation linked in the answer i cant find the relevant information or the exact/right thing to do to solve it.