# The font of the menu of a package on Debian 9 Xfce doesn't look fine

Tags: xfce, fonts, appearance, qt4

For the package GeoGebra 5, the text of the menu bar looks bad, with a strange (and unwanted) font.

[image: Font used for GeoGebra 5 menu]

This is the normal, good look of the menus of other programs:

[image: Normal appearance of the menus of other programs]

This behavior is new. It's happening since around one week ago. Before this issue, I was tired by a poor appearance of my desktop: it looked with an old-fashion; almost all the fonts of the desktop looked no so well.

So, I followed this suggestion:

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/better-font-settings-in-easy-way-xfce-and-gnome/24319

However, I didn't make the step for Qt configuration. My system works with Qt4. Maybe this is the reason for the trouble. Today, I tried with the Qt4 configuration, font substitution. However, I don't know how to manage rightly this setting. I guess that the shown font is Abydos (it appears in the Qt4 font setting window, substitution area; it's exactly the first item in my fonts list).

[image: GeoGebra 5 menu v. sample of Abydos font]

I have tried too:

- changing some options in Setting tools Appearance and Windows Manager
- uninstalling (https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package, post of user2777677), deleting the geogebra and GeoGebra folders of my .config directory, and reinstalling GeoGebra 5

without fixing the issue.

My system: Debian 9, Xfce, 64 bits

This questions could be similar to my case:

- [weird bug with xfce4: menu panel font very small](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126281/weird-bug-with-xfce4-menu-panel-font-very-small)
- [Fix for ugly fonts in programs like KeePassXC or Nextcloud on Antergos with Gnome3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443065/fix-for-ugly-fonts-in-programs-like-keepassxc-or-nextcloud-on-antergos-with-gnom)

Comment: Before the issue, I tried these guidelines too:

- https://averagelinuxuser.com/xfce-look-modern-and-beautiful/

  https://itsfoss.com/customize-xfce/

- I installed speedtest-cli (https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/check-internet-speed-with-speedtest-cli-on-ubuntu/) to check the performance of my web connection

- I installed the Microsoft fonts symbol, windings, mt extra to avoid an error under WPS (https://yepoleb.github.io/blog/2016/02/26/missing-fonts-in-wps-office/)

Comment: The font of several other items of the interface had been changed: buttons, objects tree, Welcome pop-up, etc.